# Falling objects in java?

Tags: java

We attempted to create a game in JCreator where the player catches balls falling from the top of the screen, but we aren't sure where to start. We need the balls to randomly fall from random locations (different x values), but they all fall from the top of the screen where y=0.

Comment: What do you have so far? You won't get much things here unless you show some effort.

Comment: SO is not a place to do your homework.

Comment: Someone else recently shared http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"but they all fall from the top of the screen where y=0"

This coincides with your requirement (which you mention a few lines above) so this is fine.
You just need to make the x value random. So keep y=0 as a constant, and just make the x random.

Look at this class:

[Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)

Use this method to get a random value for x:

[nextInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29)